# Why are clipboard and sound unavailable when using RemoteFX GPU?

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu, hyper-v, remotefx

I have a Windows 10 1803 Enterprise host with a Windows 10 1803 Enterprise guest running on Hyper-V. It might be worth mentioning the guest was migrated from VMware.

[image: Add/Remove Windows Features]

All of the Hyper-V Windows features are turned on on the host.

[image: Hyper-V settings Physical GPUs]

The host has a GTX 1080 for a physical GPU and it is enabled for RemoteFX.

[image: Hyper-V Settings / Management / Integration Services]

All of the Integration Services are enabled.

With no RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter installed in the virtual machine, it uses Enhanced Session Mode and it's great. I am able to copy/paste between the guest and host, I am able to play sound.

When I add a RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter to the virtual machine, I am no-longer able to copy/paste between the guest and host. There's also "No Audio Output device" installed. Removing the virtual video adapter fixes the issues immediately.

I'm unable to find documentation that you can't copy/paste or play audio with a video adapter installed.

Why are clipboard and sound unavailable when using the RemoteFX GPU?

Comment: Could be enhanced session bug: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4a976da1-eb41-49f4-89ff-a12fe3825a45/hyperv-enhanced-sessions-constantly-crash-on-win10-1709-fall-creators-rtm?forum=win10itprovirt

Comment: Here's a link to Feedback hub where you can upvote this issue: https://aka.ms/AA36dr4

Comment: RemoteFX is no-longer supported in 1809: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/1614

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Via Hyper-V console using RemoteFX GPU, audio will not work.

Workaround:
Use RDP to remote into the VM. RemoteFX and Audio will function.
VM and Host must be networked using either Internal (set static IP for host and client) or External network (via Virtual Switch Manager).

Comment: Finally, someone else who is seeing the same problem. Still able to get the full benefit of the RemoteFX GPU though?

Comment: I tried this for a week and then found that I can't connect via RDP to the RemoteFX VM AND use all of my monitors for the connection. It always fails back to using only 1. Feedback hub: https://aka.ms/AA367kr

Answer (score 0):

RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter is no-longer supported. When you attempt to add it to a VM, you'll see this:

[image: We no longer support the RemoteFX 3D video adapter. You can keep using this adapter on existing VMs, but you can't apply it to any new VMs.]

[This article](https://www.brianmadden.com/opinion/RemoteFX-vGPU-put-out-to-pasture-as-Microsoft-RDP-grows-up) from September 2018 states:

> “RemoteFX vGPU: We're developing new graphics acceleration options for
>   virtualized environments. You can also use Discrete Device Assignment
>   (DDA) as an alternative.”